# HD Webcam not utilizing full resolution

Tags: webcam, uvc, video4linux

I am using a Logitech c270h on Xubuntu 12.04 and it works with Skype, Pidgin, camorama, etc.... The issue I have is that I can not get it to utilize full resolution, which is 1280x720. `v4l-info` shows:

```
anthony@terminal:~$ v4l-info 

### v4l2 device info [/dev/video0] ###
general info
    VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
    driver                  : "uvcvideo"
    card                    : "UVC Camera (046d:0825)"
    bus_info                : "usb-0000:00:1d.2-2.2"
    version                 : 3.2.30
    capabilities            : 0x4000001 [VIDEO_CAPTURE,STREAMING]

 - SNIP -

    VIDIOC_G_FMT(VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    fmt.pix.width           : 352
    fmt.pix.height          : 288
    fmt.pix.pixelformat     : 0x47504a4d [MJPG]
    fmt.pix.field           : NONE
    fmt.pix.bytesperline    : 0
    fmt.pix.sizeimage       : 12800
    fmt.pix.colorspace      : SRGB
    fmt.pix.priv            : 0
```

This is in line with the result I experience. No HD resolution. Is there something wrong with my device, or is it a driver issue? Is there some additional configurations that can be made to get this thing working at full capacity?